# What is the chemical equation, along with the change in heat of the crystallization process of Sodium Acetate

Tags: equation-of-state

This is the reaction found in chemical hand warmers, and I can't figure out the equation and the change in heat. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_acetate#Heating_pad

Answer (score 1):

There is no chemical reaction.

The heat is released as the latent heat of crystallisation of a supercooled solution of sodium acetate trihydrate; you can obtain similar effects with sodium sulfate decahydrate or sodium thiosulfate pentahydrate.

When heated up, the hydrate dissolves in its own crystal water, which absorbs thermal energy similar to melting; when cooled down, the solution becomes supercooled.

Their state is called the *metastable state*: this means that it is not thermodynamically stable, but conditionally stable for kinetic reasons, as the crystallization requires a trigger.

The triggering can be done by, for example: insertion of a small crystal of the same salt, bending a steel chess (used in pocket heaters) or vigorous shaking.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I now understand what I need to do. Thank you!

Comment: If satisfied, you may want to mark the answer as accepted, what also marks the question as answered.